# translation of Pasch "Vorlesungen über die neuere Geometrie"

Tags: geometry, reference-request, math-history

Has Pasch "Vorlesungen über die neuere Geometrie" ever been translated?

Comment: "Lecture on the new geometry." At least we got the title translated :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could do yourself a big favor and learn German. :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen :

> Moritz Pasch, [Essays on the Foundations of Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9048194156) (Stephen Pollard editor - 2010) ?

Answer (score 1):

Pollard has translated some of Pasch.  I would check his recent article in Erkenntnis [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10670-009-9205-7).

Answer (score 1):

"Vorlesungen über die neuere Geometrie" translates into English as "Lectures on Modern Geometry." I own 2010 book edited by Stephen Pollard, titled "Essays on the Foundations of Mathematics" by Moritz Pasch, and he says that it "features [a collection of?] English translations of fourteen papers by Moritz
Pasch ... 1917-1926 ...." So this appears not to be the translation your asking about!

The German book you are asking about was published in 1882 and is here at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.153742